# Woocommerce Wordpress Website loading really slow, How to Optimize?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, page-load-time

I have been working on the following website http://katsudofightgear.com/ . I have around 40 products and around 20 categories.
The load time on pages is upwards of 8 seconds. I have no idea why this is happening. I have ran gmetrix and pingdom tests.
Pingdom tests show huge wait time . http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dLVjWX/http://katsudofightgear.com/product-category/gloves/

I have wp super cache running. Is there some settings in woocommerce or wordpress that can help me optimize so that the load times decrease. It just drives customers away when the pages cant even load. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Usually the first response is from the server end and not the website.  Unfortunately with any shared host the response time can vary because of various factors.  Just to let you know your response time is not always high.  your load time seems to vary a lot.

Comment: try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/

Comment: So its more a Godaddy is a bad server , than anything on my side?